# Is there a difference between "in the direction of (1.1)" and "in the direction toward (1.1)?"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces

The question that I have is

A differentiable scalar field f has, at the point (1.2), directional derivatives 2 in the direction toward (2.2) and -2 in the direction toward (1.1)

Determine the gradient vector at (1.2)

Here is what I did.

f'=gradient f at (1.2) x unit vector = 2

we are given that directional derivative is 2 in the direction toward (2.2)

I found out unit vector of (2.2) is (1/sqr2)(1.1)

Is my interpretation correct?

If not, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "in the direction of" and "in the direction towards" mean two different things, which can cause a lot of confusion.

If you are at the point $(1,2)$, then saying ``in the direction of $(2,2)$" would mean to use the unit vector parallel to $(2,2)$, which is what you did. However, "in the direction toward $(2,2)$" would mean that you need to find the unit vector that starts at the point $(1,2)$ and points toward the point $(2,2)$. The vector from $(1,2)$ to $(2,2)$ is $(1,0)$, which is already a unit vector, so it is the directional derivative in the direction of $(1,0)$ that is equal to $2$.